# How to provide Council the Ability to Mint/Burn tokens based on Council Proposals?

Tags: pallet-treasury, council

I am working with the staking pallet and configuring parameters. The `RewardRemainder` is receiving the issued amount based on the `imbalance` from difference to the optimal staking percentage.

How can I provide the Council the ability to burn and mint tokens directly from and to the Treasury based on a Council vote?